# Setting up DNS server to resolve request to domain "abc.com" to its own host

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, linux-networking, dns-hosting, dns-zone

I have a server with the public ip-address (lets say) 198.20.30.40

I am trying to setup a DNS server on this host so that I can resolve all request to "stackoverflow.com" being made to get resolved as the "198.20.30.40" instead of the actual stackoverflow. Of-course I have set the Primary-DNS server in the client requesting stackoverflow as 198.20.30.40. There are other open-dns server (8.8.8.8) set as secondary DNS.

After following the [tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/DNS-HOWTO-10.html), I am unable to get it to work.

This is what I am getting when I do a "dig". It looks like it is working

```
$ dig stackoverflow.com
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> stackoverflow.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43984
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;stackoverflow.com.         IN  A
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
stackoverflow.com.      86400   IN  SOA ns.stackoverflow.com. hostmaster.linux.bogus. 990 28800 7200 2419200 86400
;; Query time: 152 msec
;; SERVER: 198.20.30.40#53(198.20.30.40)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar  3 15:14:45 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 90
```

However, when I do nslookup, I get the following. It does not give the ip address of my server ie. 198.20.30.40

```
$ nslookup stackoverflow.com
;; Got recursion not available from 198.20.30.40, trying next server
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: x.y.z.d
```

Here is what my /etc/bind/named.conf.local configuration file looks like

```
zone "stackoverflow.com" {
        type master;
        notify no;
        file "/etc/bind/stackoverflow.com";
};
zone "30.20.198.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/198.20.30";
};
```

My /etc/bind/stackoverflow.com

```
$TTL 3D
@       IN      SOA     ns.stackoverflow.com. hostmaster.linux.bogus. (
                        990       ; serial, todays date + todays serial #
                        8H              ; refresh, seconds
                        2H              ; retry, seconds
                        4W              ; expire, seconds
                        1D )            ; minimum, seconds
;
                NS      ns              ; Inet Address of name server
                MX      10 mail.linux.bogus.     ; Primary Mail Exchanger
                MX      20 mail.friend.bogus.   ; Secondary Mail Exchanger
;
localhost       A       198.20.30.40
ns              A       198.20.30.40
www             CNAME   ns
media           CNAME   ns
jobs            CNAME   ns
ir              CNAME   ns
help            CNAME   ns
mail            A       198.20.30.40
```

My /etc/bind/198.20.30

```
$TTL 3D
@               IN      SOA     ns.stackoverflow.com. hostmaster.linux.bogus. (
                                989       ; Serial
                                8H      ; Refresh
                                2H      ; Retry
                                4W      ; Expire
                                1D)     ; Minimum TTL
                        NS      ns.stackoverflow.com.
40                     PTR      ns.stackoverflow.com.
40                     PTR      jobs.stackoverflow.com.
40                     PTR      help.stackoverflow.com.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your own question, you just don't realize it.

When executing `dig` without `+norecurse`, you saw:

```
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available
```

And when you tried to use `nslookup`, you saw:

```
;; Got recursion not available from 198.20.30.40, trying next server
```

You've configured an *authoritative* DNS server, which does not respond to just any DNS query. It only responds to requests for domains that have been configured. Authoritative-only servers **should not** be configured as a DNS server for use with *all recursive queries* made by a workstation or server, which is what you have done above. In other words, an authoritative-only server should never be used in the same context as a recursive server such as 8.8.8.8.

What you're encountering here is a difference in how `dig` and `nslookup` behave with this particular misconfiguration. `dig` will display a warning about recursion not being available but provide the authoritative answer if it is available. `nslookup` will also warn you that recursion is not available, but will *not* display the authoritative answer and skip to the next server entirely.

At this point it is strongly recommended to remove the authoritative-only server from your list of recursive servers, and to perform some independent research on the difference between these types of servers. While it *is* possible to configure an authoritative server to also be a recursive server, this is almost always a bad idea if this is an internet facing authoritative server as this results in an insecure configuration known as an "open resolver". (plenty of info on Google about those)